# Convert Info.plist key to array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, plist

In my `Info.plist` I have a list of countries to feed an HTML select.

The format is the following:

```
<key>HTMLSelectData</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>code</key>
            <string>AF</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Afghanistan</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>code</key>
            <string>AL</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Albania</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>code</key>
            <string>DZ</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Algeria</string>
        </dict>
```

Is there any way to convert this into a Swift Array of Dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `Info.plist` are accessible with `infoDictionary` of `Bundle`

```
let htmlSelectData = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["HTMLSelectData"] as! [[String:String]]
```

Comment: I remembered something similar but I wasn't sure and I could not find anything useful   :-)

Comment: Written that way, I could not access "name" and "code", while this way it worked: let htmlSelectData = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["HTMLSelectData"] as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

Comment: I can't believe that ,`[[String:String]]` and `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>` are synonyms

Comment: It's exactly what I thought, but when I use the first XCode says there's no member "name". What XCode dislikes is print(htmlSelectData[0]["name"]), don't ask me why, I'm really surprised